# ServiceStack unwrap exception automatically

Tags: servicestack

I found ServiceStack 4 unwrap the exception automatically, how to prevent that?

For example, I have the following API exposed.

```
public async Task GET(XXXRequest request)
{
    try
    {
    throw new Exception("#inner");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    throw new Exception("#outer", ex);
    }
}
```

And I have a logger capturing the errors

```
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature()
{
  EnableRequestBodyTracking = true,
  EnableResponseTracking = true,
  EnableErrorTracking = true,
  RequestLogger = new CustomRequestLogger()
});

class CustomRequestLogger : InMemoryRollingRequestLogger
{

    public override void Log(IRequest request, object requestDto, object response, TimeSpan requestDuration)
    {
        base.Log(request, requestDto, response, requestDuration);

        // handle errors
        HttpError httpError = response as HttpError;
        if (httpError != null)
        {
            // log error
        // httpError is #inner
        return;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that: I only captured the inner exception,  the outer exception disappeared

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable this in your AppHost with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    ReturnsInnerException = false,
});
```

Comment: worst by-default behavior ever seen.Any valid reason for this?

Comment: @mythz I am also curious about the reason for unwrapping the InnerException - would you be able to provide some info on what features are disabled when ReturnsInnerException is false?

Comment: @yenta It was to return the more useful cause of the underlying exception. This has been disabled in .NET Standard/.NET Core builds for some time as now Inner Exceptions are being concatenated in the Debug StackTrace Response Errors.